# Find good starting candidates for Newton-Raphson knowing one of the solutions of a parametrized system of nonlinear equations

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson

I have a parameterized system of equations describing the [crossed ladders problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem).

- $(x, y)$ are the $2$ horizontal distances respectively on the left/right of the junction of the ladders
- $(a, b, c)$ are parameters for, respectively; the length of the first/second ladder and the distance between the ground and the junction.

Here is my system:

$$ (x + y)^2 (x^2 + c^2) - a^2 x^2 = 0$$
$$ (x + y)^2 (y^2 + c^2) - b^2 y^2 = 0$$

I've obtained the solution $(x, y) \approx$ $(0.8572, 1.7461)$ for $(a, b, c) = (4, 3, 1)$.

Is there any way to find a function $f(a, b, c)$ that would give me a good starting candidate for my system?

Thank you.

Comment: @Moo presumably one for which Newton-Raphson then converges

Comment: Yes I want a candidate for which N-R converges. I'm trying to figure out wether or not it's possible to get an analytical form for f(a, b, c)

Comment: Must you use the given set of equations or may you use the equivalent quartic equation given in your reference? Have you tried a continuation method? Instead of solving just one problem you can consider a class of problems where the defining parameters are $t(a,b,c)$ and $t=0.1,0.2,0.3, \dotsc,1$. I suspect that the solution corresponding to t=0.1 might be a good initial guess for the case of t=0.2 and so on. Of course, this could be wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the problem ! I had a lot of fun with it. Cheers.

Comment: It would be a good exercise for you to implement the solution of the quartic equation in $T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make at least life simpler writing $$(x + y)^2 (x^2 + c^2) = a^2 x^2\tag 1$$
$$(x + y)^2 (y^2 + c^2) = b^2 y^2\tag 2$$ Make the ratio
$$\frac{x^2+c^2}{y^2+c^2}=\frac{a^2 x^2 }{b^2 y^2 }\tag 3$$ This gives two solutions
$$y_\pm=\pm\frac{a\, c \,x}{\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)\, x^2+b^2\, c^2}}\tag 4$$
Suppose that we use $y_+$ that we plug in $(1)$ to get as equation
$$\left(a^2 c^4+b^2 c^4-a^2 b^2 c^2\right)+x^2 \left(a^4-a^2 b^2+2 b^2
   c^2\right)+x^4 \left(b^2-a^2\right)+2 a c \left(c^2+x^2\right) \sqrt{(b^2-a^2)x^2 +b^2c^2}=0$$ and you can notice that we can solved for $x^2$ instead of $x$.

If $a >b$, this is limiting the search domain since we need $(b^2-a^2)x^2 +b^2c^2 \geq 0$ that is to say (admitting that we look for $x>0$) $$0 \leq x \leq \frac{b c}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$ Next, what I should do is a Taylor expansion around $x=0$ which, assuming that $a,b,c$ are all positive to get
$$\left(c^4 (a+b)^2-a^2 b^2 c^2\right)+\frac{ (a+b) \left(a^2 b (a-b)-c^2 (a-2 b)
   (a+b)\right)}{b}x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ to get an estimate
$$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{a^2 b^3 c^2-b c^4 (a+b)^2}{(a+b) \left(a^2 b (a-b)-c^2 (a-2 b) (a+b)\right)}}$$

Applied to your case $(a, b, c) = (4, 3, 1)$, the upper bound would be $\frac{3}{\sqrt{7}}\approx 1.134$ and $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{285}{434}}\approx 0.810$.

Now, Newton method will generate the following iterates
$$ \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.81035920 \\
 1 & 0.85758341 \\
 2 & 0.85721270 \\
 3 & 0.85721269
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, back to $(4)$, $y=1.74607506$.

**Edit**

We can even do better if, instead of using Taylor, we build the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant. Solving for $0$ th numerator, we get
$$x_0=\sqrt{\frac A {(a+b)B}}$$ where 
$$A=4 b^2 c^2 \left(a^4 b^3 (a-b)-a^2 b c^2 (a+b) \left(a^2+a b-3 b^2\right)+c^4 (a-2 b) (a+b)^3\right)$$
$$B=4 a^4 b^3 (a-b)^2+c^4 (a+b)^2 \left(a^3+2 a^2 b-11 a b^2+12 b^3\right)+3 a^2 b^2
   c^2 \left(-3 a^3+6 a^2 b+a b^2-4 b^3\right)$$ Applied to the example, this would give $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{26505}{37037}}\approx 0.846$.

Newton iterates would then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.84595255 \\
 1 & 0.85722574 \\
 2 & 0.85721269
\end{array}
\right)$$

For the worked example, the function we look for the zero of is
$$f(x)=-7 x^4+2 \left(4 \sqrt{9-7 x^2}+65\right) x^2+8 \sqrt{9-7 x^2}-119$$ and its $[2,2]$ Padé approximant is
$$g(x)=\frac{37037 x^2-26505}{35 x^2+279}$$ Just for curiosity, plot the two functions on the same graph. You would be amazed (I hope !).

We could still do better building the $[2,4]$ Padé approximant; the expression of $x_0$ would be really nasty but for the example we would have
$$h(x)=\frac{74568309 x^2-54285660}{20650 x^4+85245 x^2+571428}$$ giving $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{18095220}{24856103} } \approx 0.853$.

**Update**

We could make the problem simpler defining first $X=x^2$ and then $X=\frac{b^2 c^2-T^2}{a^2-b^2}$. This makes the equation to be
$$-a^4 c^4-2 a^3 c^3T+ a^2\left(a^2- b^2\right)T^2+2 a c T^3+T^4=0\tag5$$ which can be solved analytically for $T$. This quartic has two real roots since
$$\Delta=-16 a^{12} c^4 (a-b)^2 (a+b)^2 \left(\left(a^2-b^2\right)^2+27 c^4\right) < 0\qquad \qquad\forall a,b,c$$  (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)).

I suppose that the roots have opposite signs and that the one to keep is the positive root (very ugly expressions with awful radicals).

For the worked example, we should then have to solve
$$T^4+8 T^3+112 T^2-128 T-256=0$$ for which the real roots are $T=-1.06797$ and $T= 1.96375$

So, there is an explicit solution to the problem.